# i am trying to create network functions virtualization environment

Tags: networking, firewall, virtualization, scaling, network-flow

I want to create an NFV environment that is capable of auto scaling and creating a virtual firewall. I did a lot of research and I'm still confused on what are the best tools. Please I'm seeking your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I am still learning about `nfv`, but I guess you can use

- `HAproxy` as load balancer for autoscaling.
- `qemu` it can be used to create `vm` using `cli`
- `pfsense` as a firewall